# Retrieve all contact with filter first char of name

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I want to retrieve all Contact (any type, such as google sync, phone memory, sim card, etc) and showing up into many section from A-Z filtered by first char of contact name

```
String[] projection = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.STARRED};

    String orderBy = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY;
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

    String selection = null;
    Cursor cur = null;
    if (mSearchString != null) {
        selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE '"+ mSearchString +"%'";
        cur = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, null, orderBy);
    }
```

Somehow the selection is not work properly, some of Alphabet not showing my Contact. Someone can help me?

Comment: checked your code, works find for me. can you explain what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: Randomly from A-Z is not showing up. Ex, I have contact "Adam, John, Richard", which is Adam and Richard can be retrieve, not with John. When i remove the Selection, i can get it all

Comment: in my condition i cant retrieve name started with 'K'

Comment: some names have an invisible character before any real character, query for that contract's name, and print its character one by one to see if that's the case

Comment: BTW, if you're going over all letters A-Z to fill up your screen, then you're doing it wrong. you should instead make one query of all contact names, and split them by first letter in your own code, much faster then making 26 queries